# Advantages and disadvantages of auto logins

Tags: network

What are the advantages and disadvantages of auto logins from a security point of view?

Comment: Can you be clear about what you mean by autologins? On a website from a browser?

Answer (score 2):

The advantages are pretty obvious :

- no need to remember those password
- you can use very long secure passwords without the hassle of typing them all the time
- it's fast and easy

The disadvantages that I see :

- the obvious security risk : if someone gets to your computer he can access everything you have on auto log
- Somewhere the password is stored and depending how it's protected this may lead to a security risk.
- you can get used to the auto log and forget the password and if for any reason you loose the machine on which the autolog was on you will loose the password as well.

the cons can be defeated a bit with a password manager like keypass (encryption via a master password)

But it raises another con : if someone steals your master password he steals everything.

Comment: He asked about an the security point of view for advantages as well. So the advantage is not that it reduces the *hassle* of typing or *remembering* passwords, but rather reduces the risk of malware such as keyloggers getting your passwords. Also *fast* and *easy* is not a security related advantage. -1.